# Adsense multiple ads per page?

Tags: html, ads, adsense

I'm new to working with Adsense and was wondering if the way I'm putting multiple ads on my page is correct. I'm including the `adsbygoogle.js` on the footer of my page then placing the `<ins class"adsbygtoogle">` everywhere I want an ad. Is this the correct way to do this or is there a better way? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@joe-scotto

From a technical aspect this is totally fine but with doing this you will not save any external requests for `adybygoogle.js`.

Modern browsers like chrome are not loading the same js file from the same location multiple times. So it makes no difference in terms of page loading if you simply add the complete and unmodified AdSense code in place where you want the ad appear.

Just use the code below anywhere you want to get an adsense ad:

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js">   </script> 
<!-- AdSense In Content --> <ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-38359933xxxxxx"
     data-ad-slot="3352875xxx"
     data-ad-format="auto"></ins> 
<script> (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({}); </script>
```

@mike There is no official ad limit any longer. Google lift the limit of 3 ads recentely. You just need to make sure that the "ads do not exceed the content". Read here for more details about it: http://wpquads.com/google-adsense-allowed-number-ads/

Comment: I did this, but it's showing the same ad twice...any clue how to get it to display different ads?

Answer (score 0):

No, don't do this.
You can put maximum of 3 ad units and 2 link ads only.
I would say, use ad units according to your content, but you cannot use more than 3 ad units and 3 link ads.